# Convert the entity type to human readable text in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

**My browser display this type of sentence (entity).**
[CHECK IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KYiI.png)

**I want to convert the sentence like:**

Which Canadian reggae musician had a 1993 hit with the song 'Informer'?

**I'm just only fetch the data from** https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5

I'm also using JSX. Is there a way to convert those texts into human-readable text?

Comment: could use [danger set html](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) if you're using react. The issue you're running into is jsx is interpreting the text normally instead of setting content to literal html.

Comment: What does this have to do with the tag `css` ?

Comment: you can use this package to decode HTML entities https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.